# Strange behaviour of an array of objects when passed into switchMap() in RXJS

Tags: arrays, typescript, rxjs, observable, switchmap

I have a simple goal of creating an observable that emits a list of all the countries in the world. The type of the observable is `Country[]`, i.e. the store value is typed as an array of objects. However, when passed to `switchMap`, it magically gets converted into type `Country`. I have no idea what causes this behavior and if it is not, by chance, on my side. Here is the function in question:

```
public getAllCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {

      const getAppState = createFeatureSelector<ServicesState>('services');
      const getCountries = createSelector( getAppState, (state: ServicesState): Country[] => state.countries);
      // as you can see, this is the NGRX store slice that must be of type Observable<Country[]>
      const countriesFromStore$ = this.store.pipe(select(getCountries));

      return countriesFromStore$.pipe(
        // this is the switchMap that causes the error
        switchMap( countries => {
        // this is the return statement that somehow converts an array of objects into a single object??
        if (countries)  { return countries; }
        const countriesFromServer$: Observable<Country[]> = this.http.get<FilteredArrayResponse<Country>>
           (this.baseUrl, this.config.httpGetJsonOptions).pipe(
               tap( result => this.store.dispatch( new LoadCountriesAction(result.data)) ),
               map( result => result.data)
           );
        return countriesFromServer$; })
    );
  }
```

In case you have questions :

- `FilteredArrayResponse` is a generic interface with `data` attribute actually containing the array
- The full error message is `Type 'Observable<Country | Country[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Country[]>'.`
- My guess is that somehow `switchMap` confuses an Observable of Arrays with an Array of Observables...
- The return type of `result.data` is always an array
- Other operators from the `map` family exhibit the same behaviour

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio Code, hover over `countriesFromStore$` to see its type and ensure it is `Observable<Country[]>`. On the `switchMap`, hover over `countries` and make sure it is `Country[]`. I am thinking the problem lies in `const countriesFromServer$: Observable<Country[]>` where the right side of it can be `Observable<Country | Country[]>`. Remove the cast of `: Observable<Country[]>` on `const countriesFromServer$` and hover over it and see if you see `Observable<Country | Country[]>`. If so, this is the issue. You will have to go into `<FilteredArrayResponse>` for what it is.

Comment: @AliF50 I checked the types and yes I am using VSCode and it shows all the correct types. When I comment the server request with `countriesFromServer$` out overall, the problem still persisits but becomes `Type 'Observable<Country>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Country[]>'`, so it is indeed localized to the switchMap.

Comment: If you return an array in `switchMap`'s projection function it will iterate it and emit each value as a separate emission (the same applies for `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, etc..). That's why the type is `Country[] | Country`. Use `of()` as @AliF50 suggests bellow.

Comment: thanks @martin, I am trying to!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try returning `of(countries)` in the `switchMap` (`import { of } from 'rxjs';`). I think that should fix it. The `switchMap` needs to switch to an `Observable`.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
...
switchMap((countries: Country[]) => {
  if (countries) {
    return of(countries);
  }
  ....
})
```

Comment: `Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Country[]>'.`

Comment: Thanks for explaining that the switchMap return statements should always return observables, not just plain values. I got it confused. Gonna keep heading in this direction!

Comment: No problem, I edited my answer by including `countries: Country[]` in the `switchMap`. Somewhere along the lines you are losing `Country[]` and it is turning into `unknown`.